# NotImplementedException when Accessing ServiceAccountCredential C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, google-sheets-api, x509certificate2, notimplementedexception

I have a Windows app that access a Google spreadsheet to create a phone book. When I try to open the phone book, I get flagged with `System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.` I'm not really sure why, because it seems like it is being implemented?

This is the first spot that's being flagged with the issue:

```
internal object FromCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //Error flags this line
        }
```

This is the second. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with this part but it's still flagging an exception.

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://docs.google.com/feeds" }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not really sure why, becayse it seems like it is being implemented?

The giveaway is this line here:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

The `throw new NotImplementedException()` is *usually* boiler-plate from Visual Studio when stubbing out methods.

It isn't being implemented, *just because* you're calling it from the object with `.FromCertificate(certificate)`. This is just calling the method, which then runs the code within it. Ergo, it then hits your `throw new NotImplementedException();` code - thus breaking etc.

To **implement** your method, you need to remove the `throw new NotImplementedException();` and replace it with your own logic.

You will need to add some code in your `FromCertificate()` method:

```
internal object FromCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    // Do some work in here
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just to add why your "second spot" is flagging up an exception: your `NotImplementedException` from your method is bubbling back up, and the debugger is notifying you from the point at which it was called, when it returns there. If you handle (`catch`) it lower down, it will not bubble back up unless you re-throw (`throw` it again)