# ServiceAccountCredential throws Not Implemented Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, x509certificate2, service-accounts, notimplementedexception

Newbie here, excited to ask my first quetion. :-)

I am writing an app in C# with Xamarin.Forms (shproj) in Visual Studio 2015 that needs to upload a databank to a folder in my Google Drive using a service account following these [instructions](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/). I use an Android device for USB debugging. Whenever I try to create the ServiceAccountCredential that I need for the upload, a *"System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented."* is thrown. This is the corresponding flagged code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertificateBytes, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Basically, I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928423/notimplementedexception-when-accessing-serviceaccountcredential-c-sharp) with the second flag, but without having written the first part.

The upload worked perfectly before I had to change to a new Windows image and installed Visual Studio 2015 again. I tried creating a new project and reinstalling all connected packages, but still no luck...

Please, does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/Dineshbala1/GoogleDriveAPI-XamarinForms/blob/master/XamarinFormsGoogleDriveAPI-Shared/GoogleDriveShared/GoogleDriveShared/ServiceAccountCredential.cs try to use this file in your project

Comment: This worked instantly, thank you so much! :-) You're a hero!